# Sane master insurance policy for two-unit condo association

Tags: united-states, insurance, house

I live in a two-unit condo building (conversion from old house) in Massachusetts, and both units are owner occupied.

Our master insurance policy for the condo reads like it is meant for a large condo association with employees.  It is very challenging to read (and I'm an attorney) and covers all sorts of things that have no relevance to our two-unit association (e.g., external signage, liability of employees, etc.).

Do master insurance policies exist that are designed for very small condo associations with simpler needs?  I'm thinking I might save some money and it would be nice to have a simpler, understandable policy.

I called my insurance broker and they have nothing else to offer.  It would be nice to know if such things exist before I spend time looking around.

Comment: You may have better luck searching for "insuring a duplex". By definition a duplex is a "very small condo association with simpler needs". :D

Comment: @TTT, it seems that a duplex is not a condo, but I'll try searching for that.

Comment: Yeah, I had the right idea, but I was wrong to use the word "definition". After researching this a bit I see you have a dilemma. HOA master policies are very expensive, and it's exaggerated for tiny associations. To make things worse, converting a "twindominium" back to a duplex is also difficult. Your best bet might be to contact a real estate attorney to see about undoing the condo conversion. It might be worth the hassle and cost in the long run as you can likely save thousands per year on the (ridiculous) master insurance policy costs.